# Footer/Header for first page of two column article

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran, article

How can I add a footer and header just on the first page of a two column scientific article of type `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` and/or `\documentclass{article}`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to create a `firstpage` page style and apply it *after* `\maketitle` using `\thispagestyle{firstpage}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{% Page style for first page
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Footer rule
  \fancyhead[C]{My Title --- An Author}% Header
  \fancyfoot[C]{-~\thepage~-}% Footer
}
\pagestyle{plain}% Default page style

\title{My Title}
\author{An Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firstpage}% firstpage page style for first page

\lipsum[1-17]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about hitting a small bird with ICBMs ;). Here is an answer using `tikzpagenodes`:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Some title}
\author{Not me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[align=center,text=red] at ([yshift=1em]current page text area.north) {This is some
            header  text};
    \node[align=center,text=blue] at ([yshift=-1em]current page text area.south) {This is some
            footer text};
  \end{tikzpicture}%

\lipsum[1-14]

\end{document}
```

[image]